# sIFR3: controlling a and a:hover styles inside replaced through CSS rather than JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, sifr

For graceful degrading and minimal coding for the sIFR feature on my websites I would want to define styles in CSS as much as possible. Here's what I do:

• Define a H3 tag to be replaced by sIFR3.

• H3 comes in varying colors by CSS depending on it's container, say:

```
body.blue-txt h3{ color: #009CDA; }
body.white-txt h3{ color: #FFFFFF; }
body.yellow-txt h3{ color: #FFFF00; }
body.etc....
```

• H3 *might* contain an anchor (I'm aware of semantical issues, but that's just how it is at this moment... sorry)

With setting:

```
sIFR.useStyleCheck = true;
```

I thought sIFR3 would show replaced normal H3 text with correct color from my CSS-stylesheet. So far, so good: 
I can tweak e.g. blue text in sifr-config.js by using the css-parameter for sIFR.replace():

```
sIFR.replace(futura, {
  selector: 'body.blue-txt h3',
  css: 'a {color: #009CDA; }, a:hover { color: #009CDA; text-decoration: underline; }'
});
```

But that would have to be coded for every single text-color in my sIFR replacements in both JS and CSS. So I would want to make the sIFR.useStyleCheck setting just respect the CSS in sifr-config.css like:

```
body.blue-txt h3{ color: #009CDA; }
body.blue-txt h3 a{ color: #009CDA; }
body.blue-txt h3 a:hover{ color: #009CDA; text-decoration: underline; }
```

Only this doesn't seem to work ... the link text keeps popping up as #0000FF and the hover is not underlined. Is this just `Not A Feature (Yet)`, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this branch of v2.0 is what you need.

http://webdesign.maratz.com/lab/multi_color_sifr/

Another possibility is FLIR - image replacement

http://facelift.mawhorter.net/example-pages/facelift/facelift-links.html

Comment: sIFR 2 is woefully outdated. Don't go anywhere near it.

Answer (score 0):

If I may suggest, why not use @font-face? Most people have upgraded to Firefox 3+ by now, and WebKit browsers (Safari, Chrome, etc) have had it implemented for awhile, and even IE5.5+ supports @font-face. This would solve your :hover issue and would be more semantic and logical as well as much faster, but even better no Flash! ;)

But truthfully, @font-face would be the best way to go unless you are specifically targeting < IE 5.5, Firefox 2-1, or older WebKit. In all likelihood, you should hit over 90% of your desktop browser based visitors with your custom fonts.

Comment: good point, but we'll have to wait to refactor this css with @font-face; it's an existing website, which had slight problems with how sIFR was implemented.
But for new sites that's certainly a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

`useStyleCheck` has no effect on the color in the Flash movie. You need to specify all styles (except for font size) in the `sIFR.replace()` arguments.

Now, you *can* use the [`modifyCss`](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr3/JavaScript+Methods) callback to update the applied CSS based on the current style of the element being replaced. You do need to program this yourself though.

Comment: yeah, I see my code above has a *not working example* advertized as *working*, I'll change the text.
I'm not sure modifyCss() does what I would like though. 
Can't CSS `color` attribute from my stylesheet be used automagically (like font-size IS), instead of forcing it through the css-argument in sIFR.replace() ?

Comment: Sure it could, but there are other CSS properties you can specify there that can't be lifted from the browser CSS. Hence the decision not to lift anything.